# How do I send data to another screen after selection

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have a page where If you click a link, e.g. 'search' it will open a search page and you can then select an item from the gridview to use in the previous (parent) page.

I was wondering how I would go about sending back the information to the parent page and then refresh the parent page to fill in the other data?

I am guessing it will be some kind of javascript dynamically created in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

`window.opener` is the window that opened the current window.

So, if you popup a temporary window from some page, you can use window.opener from the popup window to reference the previous page objects or global variables in that page to put data back into the parent window.

Most web apps these days avoid popups because of the various popup restrictions in browsers.  Instead, folks tend to use overlays in the same window which don't run afoul of popup blockers.

For example, from the popup window, you could do something like this:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("result") = myHTML;
```

or:

```
window.opener.searchData.choice = "foo";
```

or:

```
window.opener.myFunc(data);
```

Comment: I've now heard of overlays before (surprisingly) are they known as anything else or could you give me an idea of what they are? I am interested to know because I just started an app that will use many popups and I am interested to know of a better way.

Comment: Actually after just looking into it, is the overlay simply a div on the same page that you show in focus? A bit like a modal window? if so I don't see how that would help because if you have a page with 60 popup links you would need it all on the same page?

Comment: @connersz - There are many ways to make an overlay, but it is typically a div element with content in it that is positioned with absolute position above the other elements and then made visible at the right time.

Answer (score 0):

The best way that I see is calling parent function from opener
I don't know which html has your popup page but maybe something like this:

```
//child
...
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>item 100</td>  <td><input type="button" id="searchResult100" onclick="updateParent(100)"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
...
function updateParent(id){
    if(window.opener){
         window.opener.updateData(id);
         window.close();
    }
}
```

I don't know how you want to use ID that is selected on the popup, you can hide all results that have different ID or put id inside some hiddenfield and do a postback to use the ID on the code behind. Need more information about the purpose.

```
//parent 
...
function updateData(searchId){
     // use searchId to update
}
```

Comment: If I use a gridview to pass back for example, a row ID to the parent page, how would I then refresh the parent to do a search?

Answer (score 0):

Use popup div showed when u change the value of the input , the necessary 2 steps : sending ajax data and receiving the data in the same page